# Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts when trying to run angular app after 'ng add @angular/fire'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, npm

So basically i wanted to use Firebase for my project, but i always get the same error after installing the firebase module 'ng add @angular/fire' and then running with 'ng serve':

```
Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:7708:25 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTask'.

7708     ): firebase.storage.UploadTask;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:7723:25 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTask'.

7723     ): firebase.storage.UploadTask;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:5 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

8062     get status(): number;
         ~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'get'.

8062     get status(): number;
         ~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8062     get status(): number;
             ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:9 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.

8062     get status(): number;
             ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:17 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8062     get status(): number;
                     ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:19 - error TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8062     get status(): number;
                       ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:5 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'set'. Did you mean 'Set'?

8063     set status(status: number);
         ~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts:71:13
    71 declare var Set: SetConstructor;
                   ~~~
    'Set' is declared here.


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8063     set status(status: number);
             ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:9 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.

8063     set status(status: number);
             ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:22 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

8063     set status(status: number);
                          ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:24 - error TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8063     set status(status: number);
                            ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '_codeEquals'.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:17 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'code'.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
                     ~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:21 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
                         ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:40 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
                                            ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:42 - error TS2693: 'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
                                              ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'get'.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
         ~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'serverResponse'.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:m25 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
                             ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:27 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
                               ~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:34 - error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
                                      ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:5 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'set'. Did you mean 'Set'?

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
         ~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts:71:13
    71 declare var Set: SetConstructor;
                   ~~~
    'Set' is declared here.


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'serverResponse'.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'serverResponse'.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:38 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
                                          ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:40 - error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
                                            ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:49 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
                                                     ~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8076:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NextFn'.

8076     next?: NextFn<T> | null;
                ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8077:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.

8077     error?: (error: FirebaseStorageError) => void | null;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8078:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CompleteFn'.

8078     complete?: CompleteFn | null;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8094:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.

8094     catch(onRejected: (error: FirebaseStorageError) => any): Promise<any>;
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8210:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.

8210       error?: ((error: FirebaseStorageError) => any) | null,
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8226:32 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTaskSnapshot'.

8226     snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8236:40 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTaskSnapshot'.

8236         | ((snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) => any)
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8238:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.

8238       onRejected?: ((error: FirebaseStorageError) => any) | null
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8266:28 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTask'.

8266     task: firebase.storage.UploadTask;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts[0m:8272:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

8272 }
     ~




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

5 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2023-03-22T12:00:47.506Z - Hash: 037c8c19bd477a54b8a7 - Time: 280ms

Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:7708:25 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTask'.

7708     ): firebase.storage.UploadTask;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:7723:25 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTask'.

7723     ): firebase.storage.UploadTask;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:5 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

8062     get status(): number;
         ~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'get'.

8062     get status(): number;
         ~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8062     get status(): number;
             ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:9 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.

8062     get status(): number;
             ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:17 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8062     get status(): number;
                     ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8062:19 - error TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8062     get status(): number;
                       ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:5 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'set'. Did you mean 'Set'?

8063     set status(status: number);
         ~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts:71:13
    71 declare var Set: SetConstructor;
                   ~~~
    'Set' is declared here.


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8063     set status(status: number);
             ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:9 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.

8063     set status(status: number);
             ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:22 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

8063     set status(status: number);
                          ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8063:24 - error TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8063     set status(status: number);
                            ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '_codeEquals'.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:17 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'code'.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
                     ~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:21 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
                         ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:40 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
                                            ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8067:42 - error TS2693: 'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8067     _codeEquals(code: StorageErrorCode): boolean;
                                              ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'get'.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
         ~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'serverResponse'.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:m25 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
                             ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:27 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
                               ~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8071:34 - error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8071     get serverResponse(): null | string;
                                      ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:5 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'set'. Did you mean 'Set'?

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
         ~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts:71:13
    71 declare var Set: SetConstructor;
                   ~~~
    'Set' is declared here.


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'serverResponse'.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'serverResponse'.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:38 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
                                          ~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:40 - error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
                                            ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8072:49 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

8072     set serverResponse(serverResponse: string | null);
                                                     ~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8076:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NextFn'.

8076     next?: NextFn<T> | null;
                ~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8077:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.

8077     error?: (error: FirebaseStorageError) => void | null;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8078:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CompleteFn'.

8078     complete?: CompleteFn | null;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8094:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.

8094     catch(onRejected: (error: FirebaseStorageError) => any): Promise<any>;
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8210:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.

8210       error?: ((error: FirebaseStorageError) => any) | null,
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8226:32 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTaskSnapshot'.

8226     snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8236:40 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTaskSnapshot'.

8236         | ((snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) => any)
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8238:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseStorageError'.

8238       onRejected?: ((error: FirebaseStorageError) => any) | null
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts:8266:28 - error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.storage' has no exported member 'UploadTask'.

8266     task: firebase.storage.UploadTask;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/firebase/compat/index.d.ts[0m:8272:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

8272 }
```

Initially i tried while using node 14.17.1, which I thought might be part of the problem, so then I installed node 16.19.1 with NVM, but the error persists, even in a fresh new project and i just cant get my head around it.

As for dependencies these are all i have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.4",
    "firebase": "^9.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

I have already tried out multiple node versions (14.17.1, 18.15.0 and 16.19.1) and also tried to add some configs to the 'ng add @angular/fire' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i actually managed to solve the problem. For anyone having the same issues:

This is most likely a problem due to the installation order of several node versions installed with NVM and trying to update NPM. (probably, I'm not sure)

Solve it by uninstalling node from your device, reinstalling the latest version of choice and then proceed to install other versions of earlier releases.

After that you should be able to add the @angular/fire package to your project and run it.